# Two DataTable in One Page - Second one initialising weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two `dataTable` in my page and I have a method like below:

```
function ToDataTable()
{
    $(".dataTable").css("width", "100%");

    $(".dataTable").each(function ()
    {
        var $that = $(this);

        /* Start of method */
        function ToDataTableInternal()
        {
           var table = $that.DataTable({
               responsive: {
                   details: { type: "column", target: -1 },
               },
               columnDefs: [{
                       className: "control", orderable: !1, targets: -1,
                   },
                   { orderable: !1 }],
               "paging": false,
               "ordering": false,
               "info": false,
               "searching": false,
                retrieve: true
           });
        }
        /* End of method */

        if ($that.is(":visible"))
        {
            ToDataTableInternal()
        }
        else
        {
            // Observe all invisible parents or table to trigger
            // ToDataTableInternal method if made visible
            var $arr = $(this).parentsUntil(":visible").filter(function ()
            {
                return $(this).css("display") === "none";
            }).add($(this));

            var observers = [];

            $arr.each(function ()
            {
                var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations)
                {
                    mutations.forEach(function (mutation)
                    {
                        if ((mutation.attributeName === 'style' ||
                               mutation.attributeName === 'class') && 
                                 $that.is(":visible"))
                        {
                            ToDataTableInternal();

                            for (var i = 0; i < observers.length; i++)
                            {
                                // Disconnect observers
                                observers[i].disconnect();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                observers.push(observer);
                observer.observe(this, {
                    attributes: true
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The reason I have this method is that when table's display is `none`, it really lags browser(especially IE, where I cannot do anything for minimum of 5 seconds) which is the reason of that I'm changing the table to DataTable after it made visible.

But the problem with calling methods individually is the second DataTable doesn't have the same settings which I passed on.(The first one has) Instead, second one has filters, paging, sort elements in it too.

If I call both at the same time, nothing out of ordinary happens. What may be the problem?

EDIT: I can't reproduce the same behaviour in fiddles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no problems in another environments when I'm trying to do the same thing.

An another library we use is causing problems and there is no problem with DataTable library.

Answer (score -2):

you can add following properties of dataTable in your datatable configuration to remove filtering, pageing and sorting:

### Datatable 1.9

- "bPaginate":false, //Enable or disable pagination.
- "bFilter": false, //Enable or disable filtering of data
- "bLengthChange": false, //Enable or disable the size dropdown
- "bSort": false, //Enable or disable sorting of columns.
- "bInfo": false, //Enable or disable the table information display.

**Update**

### Datatable 1.10

Option name update in datatable 1.10

- bPaginate -> paging
- bFilter -> searching
- bLengthChange -> lengthChange
- bSort -> ordering
- bInfo -> info

Comment: https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert , datatable 1.10 changed the configuration names.

Comment: As you already can see in my question, I added those parameters and my problem is a different one.